Definition of Covariance operator.
Let $x\in H$ for some Hilbertspace $H$. Recall the Covariance operator $\mathbb{E}[x\otimes x]$, where $x \otimes x := \langle x, .\rangle x$. How is actually the expectation defined in this case. For example let $H=L^2[0,1]$, then we would take the expectation over the $L^2$ functions and the ouput of the C.O. is again a $L^2$ function. How is in this case the expectation defined and also is there a typical measure one would chose on $L^2$?
